# Traer alumnos que no coincidan en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

por favor su ayuda. Tengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente lo que necesito es listar los estudiantes que **NO** se hayan inscrito en Algebra Lineal.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    e.nombre 
FROM
    estudiantes e
WHERE
     e.codigo = (
     SELECT
           NULL
     FROM
         inscripciones i
     WHERE
          i.codigo_curso != 2020)
```

NO sé si se la forma mas adecuada, porque además me sale error: 1242] [21000]: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Busca acerca del operador `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

```
WHERE
     e.codigo = (subquery)
```

Eso es porque al comparar usando `=` la subconsulta debe retornar solo un valor. En tu caso retorna varios.

Dejo consulta con explicación en comentarios:

```
select e.nombre
    from estudiantes e
    -- filtrar los estudiantes que no tienen su código en la tabla de inscripciones 
    -- con el curso 2020
    where e.codigo not in (
        -- buscar los estudiantes que han inscrito la materia con código 2020
        select codigoEstudiante from 
        inscripciones where codigoCurso = 2020
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar:

```sql
select e.* 
from estudiantes e join inscripciones i on e.codigo = i.codigoEst
where i.codigoCurs != 2020
```